How to make possible sets of parameters and ranges of prices in PostgreSQL for e-commerce filter?
I have an interface with product filters (like standard e-commerce app).

If the user chooses one/some chips in param1 then system should define available values of param2, pararm3 and min and max prices.
Than if he chooses param2 + param 1 then system should define available values of pararm3 and min and max prices and etc.
I use No Code:
Backend - Supabase (PostgreSQL)
Frontend - FlutterFlow.
DB Table Products:

How to make views or other things in Postgres to define all combinations of params to get them with API calls?
Could you give me some videos or articles?
Also I can store data in 2 tables:
I found solving with Redis bitmaps but I can't use Redis.
I tried to use view with category+param and list of available params and than intersect arrays but it is wrong logic.


